# 'undefined' value with first click on a vuetify v-chip-group v-chip

Tags: arrays, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am pretty new to Vue and vuetify, and I am running into some problems with the first click of an v-chip-group. Basically, this component prints a matrix such as this:

Threat1: AssetType1 AssetType2 AssetType3 AssetType4

Threat2: AssetType1 AssetType2 AssetType3 AssetType4

Threat3: AssetType1 AssetType2 AssetType3 AssetType4

Threat4: AssetType1 AssetType2 AssetType3 AssetType4

Basically, each threat is related to different types of assets. Both threats and Asset types are dynamc and are retrieved from a GraphQL backend.

Each row is a v-chip-group that controls the v-chips (Asset types) on that row, and the whole matrix is dinamically formed with a couple of v-fors:

```
<v-row 
  // FIRST V-FOR: prints the threat name and then moves to the v-chip-group and the second V-FOR
  v-for="(threat, index) in threats" :key="threat.name">
  <v-col>
     <v-card>{{threat.name}}</v-card>
  </v-col>
  <v-col>
    // V-model uses the index from the previous 
    <v-chip-group
       v-model="meh[index]"
       multiple
       >
       <v-chip
          filter
          v-for="type in assettypes" :key="type.short"
          @click="loadAssignation(threat.id, type.id)"
          >
       </v-chip>
    </v-chip-group>
  </v-col>

[...]

export default{
  name: 'test',
  data: function () {
    return {
      meh: [[]],
    }
},

methods: {    
  loadAssignation(threatId, assettypeId){
    console.log(this.meh[0])
  }
```

There is a "meh" array variable that is used as v-model for the v-chip-groups, using the index of the initial for. I.e. there are as many v-chip-groups as rows, and the array status of each v-chip-group is referred as meh[index]. Then:

1. The fist v-for prints the threats names from the GraphQL query array, and the second v-for prints the v-chips from the Asset types GraphQL query array.
2. When a v-chip is selected, the v-chip-group parent array is updated, and the array meh[index] (the row) is updated.

Everything seems to work properly, but I've seen that the console.log() called after the v-chip click seems to "miss" the first v-chip click, because when I click for the first time in a row, the related v-chip-group array is empty, when it should contain the array index of the v-chip of the related group.

What am I missing?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Arrays

Vue 2's reactivity system can't detect when you change an array's element using index.

The equivalent of

```html
<input v-model="yourProperty/>
```

is

```html
<input :value="yourProperty" @input="newValue => {value = newValue}
<!-- or alternatively: -->
<input :value="yourProperty" @input="value = $event"/>
```

So you need to write your own input handler that use Vue.set rather than the JavaScript = operator

So try

```html
<template>
<v-chip-group
  :value="meh[index]"
  @input="newChipGroupValue => handleInput(newChipGroupValue, indexToUpdate)"
>
...
</template>
<script>
...
methods: {
  handleInput(newChipGroupValue, indexToUpdate) {
    //remember to import Vue from vue
    Vue.set(this.meh, indexToUpdate, newChipGroupValue);
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: It's possible that the :value prop and @input event should be called differently (eg :items and @change) etc.. Make sure to use the Vue devtools (Component and Events tabs in upper right) to check what props and events does v-chip-group expect/emit

Comment: Thanks a lot, Artur. 

The thing is that the meh[ [ ] ] array is indeed being updated when I click on a v-chip, but the first click of a v-chip-group *seems* to be missed when I "track" it with console.log. However, if I check with Vue devtools, everything it is OK, and indeed, when I save the values, all of them have been recorded. I don't really need reactivity in this component, but your answer clears some concepts.

Answer (score -1):

Sir, maybe you can put the event under v-chip-group.

<v-chip-group
v-model="meh[index]"
multiple
@event here

> 